# How to save and reuse an IQueryable, or it's Where clause?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IQueryable that has a Where clause with many parameters. I could save each parameter to the ASP.NET session and recreate the IQueryable from zero, but I figured is easier to save only one parameter to the session: the IQueryable or at least the where clause of the IQueryable.
How to do this?

The query:

```
IQueryable<DAL.TradeCard> data = dc.TradeCard.Include("Address").Include("Vehicle");
data = data.Where(it =>
      (tbOrderNumber.Text == null || it.orderNumber == tbOrderNumber.Text) &&
      (tbPlateNumber.Text == null || it.Vehicle.plateNumber == tbPlateNumber.Text));
```

(now there are only 2 but there will be many more parameters)

PS: I don't want to save the query result to the session.

Comment: Some code would help..

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: What code should I add? It's an IQueryable with a where clause. I think everybody knows how that looks like.

Comment: An `IQueryable` is a runtime object. You can't save those barring serialization (and your average `IQueryable` implementation doesn't support serialization). Code showing how you're using the `IQueryable` would help us in building a solution that doesn't rely on doing the impossible.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding the question: what is this you're trying to save and why? I initially though you want a LINQ-Expression-keyed cache (so that the same LINQ queries won't be run again and again needlessly), but you're saying you don't want to save the results.

So is the query building somehow expensive? Or just bothersome?

Comment: @Gerino: the query result will be very big, so I can't save it to the session

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but you could try to use [`DataContext.GetCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand.aspx) to get the SQL command for the query and then save it to use it with [`DataContext.ExecuteQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had whole big answer ready but I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve :)

Ok, so let me write out what I think you're trying to do:

- Server gets request ("get data for paramA = 1, paramB = 2, ... paramZ = 24")
- Server runs a series of "Where" and gets a filtered result set
- Server sends data to client
- Client does some stuff that operates on the same set of filtered data. But you don't want server to re-run the query! And you cannot save the data to client's session cause it's a lot of records.
- Until client explicitely calls the query with different params, the query should not be re-run

I was working on simillar problem lately, but there isn't one magic bullet :)

Some ideas for the solution:

1. Cache list of ID's. Unless the data goes into hundreds of thousands records, you probably can save the indexed Id of the selected items to the session. It's what, 4-8 bytes per ID + overhead? But that does re-runs the query, just more more efficiently: `data = source.Include("...").Where(i => IdsFromSession.Contain(i.Id));`
2. (Added in edit) Cache the query input string/object/however your search values are passed. You can probably fairly easily serialize it and use that (or hash of that) as a server-side cache key.
3. (I love the idea, but it's a bit wonky :) ) Cache the Wheres! Now, this workes like this:

   1. Create method that takes expressions instead of Funcs
   2. Write your where lambdas to that method and have that magic method actually return Funcs for "Where"
   3. Get an unique hash for the where lambdas
   4. Check the server-side cache for that hash, if needed run the query and save the results under that hash.

Now, this is a huge overkill and overengineered solution, but I am personally dying to actually implement this. It would look like this:

```
class MagicClass{ // don't have time for name-inventing :)
    private List<string> hashes = new List<string>();
    public string Hash {get{ return String.Join("_", hashes);}}
    public Func<TIn,bool> MagicWhere(Expression<Func<TIn,bool>> where){
        var v = new MagicExpressionVisitor();
        v.Visit(where);
        hashes.Add(v.ExpressionHash);
        return where.Compile(); // I think that should do...
    }
}

class MagicExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
     public string ExpressionHash {get;set;}
     // Override ExpressionVisitor methods to get a possibly unique hash depending on what's actually in that expression
}
```

Usage:

```
var magic = new MagicClass();
data = data.Where(magic.MyWhere<DAL.TradeCard,int>(it => it.IsSomething && it.Name != "some name"));

if(!Cache.HasKey(magic.Hash))
    Cache[magic.Hash] = data.ToList();
return Cache[magic.Hash];
```

This is obviously untested, but doable. It won't execute the Wheres on data source, if such query was already run (in cache period). It has two advantages over caching Id's: 1. It works for many clients simultanously (so second client will benefit from the fact, that the first one requested the same query, 2. It doesn't touch the datasource at all.

If the datasource is DB, you can probably find out what is the actual SQL command being run, SHA-### it and save results under that hash, but my crazy solution works for other datasources, like LINQ-to-Objects etc. ;)